# Как отключить SIP macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, sierra

Пробовал делать как написано в [инструкции](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-mac/), но в режиме восстановления нет вкладки "Utilities", не могу запустить терминал. У меня MacBook Pro 2010, может быть в этом причина? Вот как выглядит панель в режиме восстановления: https://yadi.sk/i/us0Q3zwW3D2PtP

Comment: надо нажать далее на окне "Install macOS Sierra" и дальше должен быть выбор терминала

Answer (score 0):

Вот, можно сделать так:
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25359?locale=ru_RU

1. Выберите меню «Apple» > «Перезагрузить» или нажмите кнопку включения питания, если компьютер Mac выключен.
2. При запуске Mac нажмите сочетание клавиш Command-S.

*Отображается экран черного цвета со стандартным белым текстом. Теперь Вы можете запускать необходимые Вам команды UNIX.*

Comment: Не получилось, пишет что это можно сделать только в режиме восстановления системы.